# Save updates to Core Data object

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a Core Data object that is created in one tab and located in another via UUID. It can be updated in the second tab by clicking on the "Save" button.

Currently, when the "Save" button is clicked, the changes to the object are shown across all sheets, but when I close the app and open it again the object has gone back to how it was before.

The "Save" button currently has a similar logic to in [this post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/update-data-using-core-data/1222). I think what could be missing is to add `try viewContext.save` to the "Save" button, but I'm not sure how to do this without creating a new object (as opposed to updating the existing one.

Any ideas? Thank you! (and please let me know if I need to add more context, I think this is the right amount but wasn't totally sure).

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ModifySheet: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Items>
    var items: FetchedResults<Items> {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    
    @State var newCost: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
            Form {
                    Slider(value: $newCost, in: 0...100)
        }
                Button(action: {
                    items[0].cost = newCost
                })
                {Text("Save")}
    }
}
    
    init(filter: UUID) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Item>(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", filter as CVarArg))
    }
}
```

Comment: try viewContext.save() will not create new objects by itslef, it will save any changes you have done like creating, updating or deleting objects.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to add something else to the button as well though, because when I add in try viewContext.save() directly I get the error "Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '() -> Void'". Probably something like a "do" or "let" command, but not entirely sure how they work.

Comment: `do {...} / catch { print(error) //or something }`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried                    
`do {items[0].cost = newCost
try viewContext.save()}`                    
but not working :-( ("Invalid conversion..." error again)

Comment: Could just be that I am not writing the `do` correctly. I am super new to all this.

Comment: `do { try viewContext.save() } catch { print(error) }`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! N.b. I also had to add the context in: `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext`. I have updated this in the original question.